# readOGR with geojson giving me "cannot open file" error

Tags: r, geojson, rgdal, ogr

I'm pretty new to using `rgdal` so I'm hoping this is something simple that I'm missing, but I've been googling around about it for a few hours and I can't figure out the issue.

Basically I'm trying to make a leaflet map in a shiny app, but I'm getting snarled right at the beginning, trying to load country data like so:

```
library(rgdal)

countries <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

but every time I get the following error:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file
```

I've gone to the address and I see the raw geojson file there, so it's not a missing file.  I've also downloaded the [file](https://github.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m) manually into a data folder and then tried to access it with

```
countries <- readOGR("data/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

and I get the same error.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

I'm running R on Windows 7.

Comment: On Linux, it works for me with `countries <- readOGR("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")`. Note that you forgot a `-` between `geo` and `boundaries` in the address.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `drv <- ogrDrivers(); drv[drv$name == "GeoJSON",]`?

Comment: Thanks Pascal.  I did have the ` - ` in the program, just missed it in the copy.  Anyway, the `drv`... command gives me `12 GeoJSON  TRUE` so I'm not sure that's much help.  Any other drivers I should check on?  I reinstalled the rgdal package too, thinking that might be the problem.  Somewhat baffled.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: It was to check whether the GeoJSON driver is available, which seems to be the case. I don't see the reason for you to not be able to read the data, as it works for me.